# Pointer deferencing and manipulating objects which are being pointed to - equivalent constructs in Java

Tags: java, c++

Hello
In C++ you can do the following:

```
int x = 5

cout << x;
// prints 5

int* px = &x;

(*px)++;
cout <<x;
// prints 6
```

Is there an equivalent construct in Java

Comment: That code snippet does not have any pointers to pointers.

Comment: Nor is it C++. It is C. So though it can be used from C++ a real C++ program is more likely to use a reference.

Comment: @Martin -- I'm pretty sure that's C++ and not C.  Unless there's an integer called cout declared.

Comment: @PigPen: OK Mr Pedantic. Its `C with classes`. Writing C in a C++ file does not make it C++

Comment: Oops... I orignally wanted to ask a question about pointers to pointers, but changed my mind. Will change the title... Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Martin -- What you mean is that you would never write code like that in a professional C++.  But you would never write code like that in professional C either.  Code like the above is what's used to teach beginners how pointers work.  Pointers do exist in C++, and every C++ programmer should know how to use them, even if they aren't used as often as in C.  I just think that telling a beginner that the code is not C++, when it clearly is, is misleading.  But maybe you take a different approach, I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to create an object that contains an int.  Then, you can pass around a reference to that object, and you can increment the int that's in that object.  But there's no way that you can have another reference to the same int and increments in one will increment the other -- unless both cases are references to the same wrapper object.

Comment: +1, there's even a generic class that already does this: [Holder<T>](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Holder.html)

Comment: That won't work in this particular case because `Integer` is immutable: you can pass a Holder<Integer> object around, but you still can't change the Integer it holds.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "sort of".  As long as you're dealing with primitives, just wrap the value in an array.

```
int[] a = {5};
int[] b = a;
b[0]++;
System.out.println(a[0]);
```

As others have pointed out, for more complex problems, your best bet is always to create an object with an 'increment' or 'set' method that modifies a stored value.

Comment: Does Java not do auto-boxing of primitives.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at, but I'll try to respond.  Java only auto-boxes primitives when converting to and from the auto-boxing wrapper Classes (ie Integer, Short, Long, etc...).  Otherwise Java does indeed treat primitive types as primitives.  http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/basic_types/autoboxing.html shows how some code statements in Java are interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Not as such.

You can think of Java as passing everything by reference, so

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
Foo f2 = f1;
```

means `f2` and `f1` point to the same object (unlike C++ where the assignment would make a copy). Equivalent C++ code would make `f2` a `Foo&`.

Java will autobox `int`s to `Integer`s, but `Integer`s are immutable. So you need to either write your own `MutableInteger`, or use something like the `java.util.AtomicInteger` if you want to pass by reference and change values as a side effect (which I suspect is your underlying motive).

Sadly you can't override operators in Java so the syntax will be more verbose then equivalent C++ code.

Comment: sadly? that's one of java's features :-)

Comment: Heh. It would be nice sometimes. So would `const`, for that matter (and no, `final` just doesn't cut it).

Comment: BTW Java passes everything by value, even references. There is no call by reference in Java.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? EDIT: I said "You can think of Java as passing everything by reference". Emphasis on "you can think". For a C++ programmer this is the best way to transition to Java-land.

Answer (score 0):

No... Java abstracts away the concept of pointers and memory locations. Pointers, and pointer dereferencing are not possible in Java.